# postgres creating new user/role

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I am following this tutorial, and being logged in as postgres I run:
`createuser --interactive`

provided name and choosen superuser

then:

`createdb dogspot`

but when trying

`sudo -i -u dogspot`

I get:

```
postgres@ip-172-31-12-126:/home/ubuntu$ sudo -i -u dogspot
sudo: unknown user: dogspot
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

but the user exists for sure, because when trying to once more creatuser there is prompt about already existing one. Some hints how to do it correctly will be apriciated.

db version:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4
```

os version:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

UPDATE:

seems that all was needed wat to creat linux user before with coresponding name:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/dogspot -m dogspot

sudo passwd dogspot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing PostgreSQL users and operating system users.

A PostgreSQL user may exist without a corresponding operating system user.

By default, connections use `peer` authentication, where you must be running as the OS user with the same name as the PostgreSQL user you try to connect to. [You can change that in `pg_hba.conf` though](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), for all users or just for some users/DBs. For more detail see the [client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html) chapter.